# issue with variable for loop java

Tags: java

I am complete beginner. I have a for that prints with a syso the value of a jsonText. How can I do to save this value in a variable concatening all the values of the length of the for. here is my code. Thank you.

```
for(int i=0;i<nodes.getLength();i++) {
    Element element = (Element)nodes.item(i);

    Map<String, String> obj=new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    obj.put("category",getElementValue(element,"category"));
    obj.put("title",getElementValue(element,"title"));
    obj.put("date",getElementValue(element,"pubDate"));
    obj.put("description",getElementValue(element,"description"));
    obj.put("content",getElementValue(element,"content:encoded"));
    StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
    JSONValue.writeJSONString(obj, out);
    String jsonText = out.toString();
    System.out.println(jsonText);

}
```

Comment: See class StringBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a StringBuilder to concatenate the jsonText.

```
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   for(int i=0;i<nodes.getLength();i++) {
      Element element = (Element)nodes.item(i);

      Map<String, String> obj=new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
      obj.put("category",getElementValue(element,"category"));
      obj.put("title",getElementValue(element,"title"));
      obj.put("date",getElementValue(element,"pubDate"));
      obj.put("description",getElementValue(element,"description"));
      obj.put("content",getElementValue(element,"content:encoded"));
      StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
      JSONValue.writeJSONString(obj, out);
      String jsonText = out.toString();
      System.out.println(jsonText);
      builder.append(jsonText);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you, but later I do a Syso of the builder and not displays all the content, perhaps the content is so long, is there a solution for that? Thank you

Comment: You have a very long string? You should receive a  `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error if it can't append all the Strings. Maybe your terminal can't/won't display very long strings. You can use the method length() to see what is the actual length of the StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i<nodes.getLength();i++) {
    ..... your existing code ....
    builder.append(jsonText);
}

String finalData = builder.toString();
```

Comment: Thank you, but later I do a Syso of the builder and not displays all the content, perhaps the content is so long, is there a solution for that? Thank you

Answer (score -2):

You could create a global variable outside the for-loop:

```
String allStrings = "";
```

then use the string1.concat(string2); method:

```
allStrings = allStrings.concat(jsonText);
```

Comment: Strings are immutable and this means that allStrings variable never gets updated. The concat method will return always the last jsonText and nothing more.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry, I forgot to add something to the code. If you write allStrings = allStrings.concat(jsonText); it will work.